# How to customize TwitterBootstrap MVC HTML Helpers with additional css classes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

We're working on a project with TwitterBootstrapMVC and we wish to incorporate Google's material design.  We've found a nice bootstrap / material implementation: http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/.

However, in order to harness the power of this material framework we'd like to add css classes to certain things.  For example, a FormGroup() might need to be extended with **label-floating** and **has-warning**.  We would like to extend or customize some of the default behavior of the TwitterBootstrapMVC extensions.

How should we go about that?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should have pointed out I know about the .Class() method.  But, this is a very large site.  There will be literally thousands of fields across hundreds of views.  If we decide that we want a class like "label-floating" on our default FormGroups, then I wanted to help the developers ensure consistency by baking those conventions into our HtmlHelpers.

Comment: You could create your own helpers that use the `.Class()` method

Answer (score 0):

According [the docs](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/Documentation), you can use the `Class(string)` method to add classes to any control.

```
.Class("cool-css-class")
```

> Assures that specified class will be applied to the element.